# Errors with Selenium and Python and Using Chrome Driver after upgrade to a version >89

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I have the following configuration, which works perfectly in it's current form.

I can use any chrome/chromedriver under v89 without any issues
Once I pass the v89 mark, it does not work anymore, giving the below error

Any help would be appreciated, since I am going crazy with this.

I tried different approaches, like using the automatic webdriver-manager installer, but failed in each attempt.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/opt/program/src/steps/start_browser_step.py\", line 30, in handle\n    browser = self.browser(options, service)\n  File \"/opt/program/src/steps/start_browser_step.py\", line 105, in browser\n    browser = ChromeBrowser(options=options, service=service)\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py\", line 81, in __init__\n    super().__init__(\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py\", line 106, in __init__\n    super().__init__(\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 288, in __init__\n    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 381, in start_session\n    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py\", line 444, in execute\n    self.error_handler.check_response(response)\n  File \"/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py\", line 249, in check_response\n    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)\nselenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n  (chrome not reachable)\n  (The process started from chrome location /opt/program/bin/chrome-linux/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)\nStacktrace:\n#0 0x00400084a262 <unknown>\n#1 0x00400083b133 <unknown>\n#2 0x004000545ce1 <unknown>\n#3 0x00400056cf1c <unknown>\n#4 0x004000568c4e <unknown>\n#5 0x0040005ae38d <unknown>\n#6 0x0040005a4d83 <unknown>\n#7 0x004000573552 <unknown>\n#8 0x00400057478c <unknown>\n#9 0x0040007f33f6 <unknown>\n#10 0x004000809858 <unknown>\n#11 0x0040008090ff <unknown>\n#12 0x00400080a015 <unknown>\n#13 0x004000810cd3 <unknown>\n#14 0x00400080a39b <unknown>\n#15 0x0040007e51e7 <unknown>\n#16 0x004000827848 <unknown>\n#17 0x00400082798f <unknown>\n#18 0x004000835256 <unknown>\n#19 0x004002768fa3 start_thread\n#20 0x004002d244cf clone
```

This is the version I am trying to use, which does not work. I also tried with 110, 100, 90 ... all of them failed

```
ARG CHROME_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1109227%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media"
ARG CHROMEDRIVER_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1109227%2Fchromedriver_linux64.zip?alt=media"
```

The below code works perfectly. The issue happens only when I use the above drivers.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/bitnami/python:3.8.12

ARG CHROME_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F843831%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media"
ARG CHROMEDRIVER_URL="https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F843831%2Fchromedriver_linux64.zip?alt=media"
ARG 

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
RUN apt-get install python3-dev -y
RUN apt-get install gcc g++ -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y xvfb
RUN apt-get install -y packagekit-gtk3-module
RUN apt-get install -y libx11-xcb1
RUN apt-get install -y libdbus-glib-1-2
RUN apt-get install -y libxt6
RUN apt-get install -y libnss3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
RUN apt-get install -y libasound2
RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get install -y fonts-indic
RUN apt-get install -y fonts-noto
RUN apt-get install -y fonts-noto-cjk

RUN mkdir -p /opt/program
RUN mkdir -p /opt/program/data
RUN mkdir -p /opt/program/bin/tmp

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list

RUN wget $CHROME_URL -O /opt/program/bin/tmp/chrome.zip
RUN unzip /opt/program/bin/tmp/chrome.zip -d /opt/program/bin

RUN wget $CHROMEDRIVER_URL -O /opt/program/bin/tmp/chromedriver.zip
RUN unzip /opt/program/bin/tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt/program/bin


ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=TRUE
ENV PATH="/opt/program:${PATH}"

COPY . /opt/program
WORKDIR /opt/program

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python", "-v"]
```

```
autopep8==1.5.5
beautifulsoup4==4.10.0
black==20.8b1
boto3==1.17.2
Faker==11.3.0
flake8==3.8.4
html5lib==1.1
ImageHash==4.2.1
importlib-metadata==4.11.3
mergedeep~=1.3.4
mock==4.0.3
moto==1.3.14
numpy==1.22.4
Pillow==9.3.0
pre-commit==2.10.1
pytest==6.2.4
pytest-cov==2.12.0
pytest-env==0.6.2
pytest-pythonpath==0.7.0
python-dotenv==0.15.0
pyYAML==5.4.1
requests==2.25.1
requests-mock==1.9.3
scipy==1.8.1
selenium==4.6.0
webdriver-manager==3.8.5
```

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome as ChromeBrowser
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

options = ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/opt/program/bin/chrome-linux/chrome'

user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' \
             'CriOS/85 Version/11.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--hide-scrollbars')
options.add_argument('--window-size=1400,1080')
options.add_argument('--disable-cache')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--kiosk')

service = ChromeService(executable_path='/opt/program/bin/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')

browser = ChromeBrowser(options=options, service=service)
```

Comment: The error was thrown in:  `browser = self.browser(options, service)` so may be some options are messed up. I wonder if it because of the `user-agent`. It should be: `options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={user_agent}')
`

Comment: @TamTam nop, same thing unfortunately. As I was saying, the above code works with chrome <=v89 ..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this whole thing happened because I have a M1 processor. For some reason, up till v89, the above scripts work with my processor as well. After that, they dont anymore ... but on Intel processors, everything is fine.
Pretty weird to be honest, but ...